# CSS file won't apply to Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

Trying to apply some basic CSS to a button on my LWC and can't seem to get it to apply. I followed all the basic guidelines in terms of containing the CSS file within the same folder as my LWC. It deploys without issue

```
=== Deployed Source
STATE  FULL NAME                     TYPE                      PROJECT PATH                                                  
─────  ────────────────────────────  ────────────────────────  
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Add    pcMaterials\pcMaterials.css   LightningComponentBundle  force- 
app\main\default\lwc\pcMaterials\pcMaterials.css

Add    pcMaterials\pcMaterials.html  LightningComponentBundle  force- 
app\main\default\lwc\pcMaterials\pcMaterials.html     

Add    pcMaterials\pcMaterials.js    LightningComponentBundle  force- 
app\main\default\lwc\pcMaterials\pcMaterials.js  

Add    pcMaterials\pcMaterials.js    LightningComponentBundle  force- 
app\main\default\lwc\pcMaterials\pcMaterials.js-meta.xml
```

It has the same name as the LWC so it should be applied automatically (at least according to the documentation

HTML File

```
<template>
   <lightning-card   variant="narrow"
                  icon-name="standard:opportunity"
                  title="PC Materials">
    <lightning-button label="New" slot="actions" class="normalField"> 
    </lightning-button>
    <lightning-button label="All"></lightning-button>
    <lightning-button label="My Materials" onclick={handleClick}></lightning- 
    button>
        <!--<lightning-input type="search"
        onchange={handleSearchTermChange}
        variant="label-hidden"
        class="slds-m-bottom_small"
        label="Search"
        placeholder="Search"
        value={searchTerm}>
        </lightning-input>-->
        <lightning-datatable
            key-field="id"
            data={aidata}
            hide-checkbox-column = true
            columns={columns}
            onsave={handleSave}>
        </lightning-datatable>
   </lightning-card>
</template>
```

CSS File

```
.normalField {
    color: red;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CSS is being "applied", but the problem is that you can't modify most attributes of a component because of the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_dom). This means that you **can**, for example, set the border of a component, or its width and height, but you **can't**  change its font color or other attributes. You'll want to read more about the current limitations for [CSS styles](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_css) in components. The only allowed color changes are to use the `variant` attribute to change the color. For example, you could say:

```
<lightning-button label="New" slot="actions" variant="destructive"></lightning-button>
```

Check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:button/specification) for other possible variants.

If you need greater control than what's allowed by the component, you'll need to write your own instead. You can use lightning [buttons](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/buttons/) from SLDS to get started.

Comment: bit frustrating but makes sense in the longrun. Thought the switch to component specific CSS would allow more functionality in that regard, not less

Answer (score 0):

Set your `lightning-button` *variant* to *base*. By default, a button's variant is `neutral` and that sets the background to be white which is overriding the CSS applied in some way.

See an example in the playground here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/AX7c7dCxd/1/edit

This all being said, if you need to totally customize your button, don't use the `lightning-button` component and instead use an HTML button or create your own button component.

Answer (score 0):

//Create a css with name fileNameStyles.css and upload it in static resource
//with public & static resource name as fileNameStyles

//Add below code in your JS

```
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import Styles from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/fileNameStyles';

export default class yourComponentName extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

renderedCallback() {

        // Loading external CSS File
        Promise.all([
            loadStyle(this, Styles)
        ]).then(() => { })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error.body.message);
            });

    }
}
```

//Your css will get applied